# How to pull all items within a specifc folder located on external git repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket, git-pull

I am trying to pull all the files and folders within a specific folder in my git repository. I have already tried using sparce-checkout but this pulls the specific folder. I wish for it to only pull the files within the folder.

I have a folder called /EWINS/ and I wish to pull every folder and file within that directory.

I have tried:

`git init`

`git config core.sparseCheckout true`

`git remote add -f origin https://MYDIRECTORY`

`echo "EWINS/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout`

`git pull origin master`

However this results in the folder EWINS being pulled where as I require all the items within EWINS. Specifically I do not want the EWINS folder, simply all of the items within it.

I could theoretically specify every single file I want and that will work but I will have to be editing the script every time a new item which needs to be managed is added, and this is not appropriate.

**I have referenced:**

[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

http://lakehanne.github.io/git-sparse-checkout

Any help would be appreciated.

**Example:**

I receive:

EWINS\app.test , text.txt, note.pad

I want:

app.test, text.txt, note.pad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Git sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout) still uses the working tree to restore its content. That means you would always get the `EWINS` folder.

My workaround would be to do this checkout in a dedicated folder, and then make a mirror-rsync with the right folder (which would be outside the Git repo, not managed by Git at all).

Comment: Yea I was fretting having to another step. Always could run two scripts was just hoping there was some simple step I was missing. I will choose this as the answer if nothing else comes up.